# How to disable a button view access permission which is coming from data base

Tags: angular, service

I have a list of names coming from backend with view permission but i need to disable only the first name view permission. Kindly help.
I will share TS code here:

```
this.ApiService
                .getAccessGroups()
                .subscribe(
                  groups  => {
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(groups));
                    groups[0].pages.sort(function(a, b) {
                      return (a._id - b._id);
                    });
                    groups = groups.sort(function(a,b) {
                      if(b.group.groupName && a.group.groupName) {
                        if(a.group.groupName.toLowerCase() < b.group.groupName.toLowerCase()) return -1;
                        if(a.group.groupName.toLowerCase() > b.group.groupName.toLowerCase()) return 1;
                      }
                      return 0;
                    })
                    this.groups = groups;
                  }
```

JSON Data:

[{"_id":23,"view_id":2,"accessgroup_id":4,"permission":true,"view_permission":true,"viewName":"history"},{"_id":24,"view_id":3,"accessgroup_id":4,"permission":true,"view_permission":true,"viewName":"account"},{"_id":25,"view_id":4,"accessgroup_id":4,"permission":true,"view_permission":true,"viewName":"projects"},{"_id":26,"view_id":5,"accessgroup_id":4,"permission":true,"view_permission":true,"viewName":"department"},{"_id":27,"view_id":6,"accessgroup_id":4,"permission":true,"view_permission":true,"viewName":"users"},{"_id":28,"view_id":7,"accessgroup_id":4,"permission":true,"view_permission":true,"viewName":"userAccess"},{"_id":22,"view_id":1,"accessgroup_id":4,"permission":true,"view_permission":true,"viewName":"tracking"}]}]

I need to disable tracking view permission condition. Please help

Comment: is that the console result of `console.log(groups)` if yes, type `console.log(JSON.stringify(groups))` and add result in question

Comment: ya i will add please check. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try either of these two methods, to make tracking view_permission false as you asked in the question.

Above this line,

```
this.groups = groups;
```

**Method1:**

```
groups.forEach(function(group) {
  if(group.viewName == 'tracking')
 {
  group.view_permission = false;
 }
});
```

**Method2:**

```
 for (var i in groups) {
     if (groups[i].viewName == 'tracking'){
        groups[i].view_permission = false;
        break;
     }
   }
```

Edit: According to our discussion, this change in html needed,

```
<td> 
<md-slide-toggle [disabled]="!this.isPermission" [(ngModel)]="page.view_permission" (change)="viewChange(page)" style="width: 40px;margin: 0 auto;"></md-slide-toggle> 
</td>
```

Comment: ya i will check and update.. getting error as Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined in method1

Comment: whats `console.log(this.groups)` results in?

Comment: undefined i got

Comment: I changed the answer, now add it above `this.groups` and loop `groups`

Comment: 0:group:{_id: 4, groupName: "admin", company_id: 3}
pages:Array(7)
0:accessgroup_id:4
permission:true
viewName:"tracking"
view_id:1
view_permission:true
_id:22
__proto__:Object

Comment: 1:{_id: 23, view_id: 2, accessgroup_id: 4, permission: true, view_permission: true, …}
2:{_id: 24, view_id: 3, accessgroup_id: 4, permission: true, view_permission: true, …}
3:{_id: 25, view_id: 4, accessgroup_id: 4, permission: true, view_permission: true, …}
4:{_id: 26, view_id: 5, accessgroup_id: 4, permission: true, view_permission: true, …}
5:{_id: 27, view_id: 6, accessgroup_id: 4, permission: true, view_permission: true, …}
6:{_id: 28, view_id: 7, accessgroup_id: 4, permission: true, view_permission: true, …}
length:7

Comment: i got above console for this.groups

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151459/discussion-between-sravan-and-tulsi).